# converting string to date, and getting difference in days

Tags: delphi

I have strings in the following format e.g. `20110201` and I want to convert it to a date in delphi, then subtract it from today to get the number of days difference.

How can I do that?
Sorry for my english.

Comment: If you find an answer to your question, you can accept by clicking tick mark at the left of the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The functions you need are `Copy` (to retrieve parts of your input string), `StrToInt`  (to convert the string parts to integers), `DateUtils.EncodeDate` (to create a `TDate` from the integers), `Now` (to retrieve the current date as `TDate`) and `DateUtils.DaysBetween` (to get the difference between two dates in days).

I think you can figure out the rest on your own using the Delphi help for these functions.

Comment: But how to convert DaysBetween result to integer? I'm using floattostr to display that amount, but i'm always getting '3,26677404491323E268'...

Comment: `DaysBeween` _does_ return an integer.

Comment: If you use "Date" instead of "Now" there should be no fraction and no need to call DaysBetween, just substract the 2 values from each other.

Comment: Use Trunc() instead of Round. It simply returns the whole number portion (without the decimals) as an Int64. Then you don't need DaysBetween; simple integer math will give you the number of days.

Answer (score 5):

Use Copy to extract the 3 substrings for year, month, day. Then StrToInt to convert them into integers, then EncodeDate to turn the 3 integers into a TDateTime.

TDateTime is a float, counting whole days before the decimal point and the time at that day as the fraction after the decimal point.

In SysUtils there is a function called Date: TDateTime which returns the current date.

You can simply substract the TDateTime you parsed out of the string from the value returned by Date to get the number of days difference between them.